# Using dynamic value in JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a json file (myJson.json) in which I am adding a dynamic value

```
[
  {
    "menu":"<?php echo $r; ?>",
  }
]
```

Now I am accessing this JSON in my Php file as :

```
$r="HOME";
$str_data = file_get_contents("MyJson.json");
$data = json_decode($str_data,true);
var_dump($data[0]['menu']);
```

output:"`<?php echo $r; ?>`"
Is there any way to get "HOME" as an output?

Comment: try `$data[0]['menu']=$r;`

Comment: parse the json, set the value and you're done. `json_decode` and `json_encode` make this a pretty trivial task...

Comment: can you change the json? (it's not json if you have a php code)

Comment: @Chumkiu...what else can I do?

Comment: I am developing a dynamic menu in my Php site .where some values should dynamically appended to my menu.<br>eg . message(10),chat(5)

Comment: here 10 and 5 comes from database

Answer (score 2):

You may try like

```
[
  {
    "menu":"r",
  }
]
```

and is json

```
$r="HOME";
var_dump($$data[0]['menu']);
```

You will get home as an output

Answer (score 0):

Can you just keep placeholder in your JSON and then substitute it with valid value?
Like, 
`[
  {
    "menu":"@@HOME@@",
  }
]`

Then string replace that string with $r.